# MongoDB Bulk operations performance is slow for Updates

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, nosql, database-performance

I am new to Mongo.
I was playing around with Spring Boot MongoRepositories and MongoTemplate. For this I did some sample application. Please find code from GIT Repository [here](https://github.com/ereshzealous/spring-mongo-bulk-updates)

For this use case I have inserted 5000 randomly generated data and inserted in my Mongo Local instance. I tested inserting data using repository.saveAll() and batch update of Mongo Template

```
Document document = new Document();
generateUserDetailsDocument(details, document);
documents.add(new InsertOneModel<>(document));
```

The average time for above use cases are

1. Repository -- 4.5 seconds, which is large compare to RDBMS.
2. MongoTemplate -- 3.5 seconds, which is large compare to RDBMS.

Now I tried with update data, for this case I loaded top 5000 records and for each record updated one of the property value and tried to repeat the same process.

**Repository -- saveAll().** and for 
 **Mongo Template**

```
    Document document = new Document();
    generateUserDetailsDocument(details, document);
    UpdateOptions updateOptions = new UpdateOptions();
    updateOptions.upsert(true);
    documents.add(new ReplaceOneModel<>(new Document("_id", details.getId()), document));
    userDetailsMongoCollection.bulkWrite(documents, new BulkWriteOptions().ordered(false));
```

Now I cound see very huge difference in time

1. Repository -- 10 seconds, High compare to RDBMS.
2. Mongo Template -- 30 seconds, Very high compare to above case.

Does NOsql inserts take more time compare to RDBMS? Is it related to collection structure? 
How to improve above case for high performance. I followed latest documentation from Mongo official site.

Any help is highly appreciated.

regards
Eresh